# How to serve a static html that has a php extension with S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I can't change the extension of the file, but I need to serve it as a html file. No php inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work fine.  Set the `Content-Type` to `text/html`.

You can do this in the S3 console, described in [How do I add metadata to an S3 object?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html) or when you initially upload the file.